# Angular Google Map flikering issue (ng-cloak, ng-bind is not working!)

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps, ng-bind

I'm having trouble with flikering problem in Angular Google Map.

I have a problem in this **Plunker**.
http://plnkr.co/edit/f2gxG7DM1U8IlOXfRiuT?p=preview

When I click the marker, **infowindow** is flikering before it shows the information. I tried **ng-cloack, ng-bind**

`<div ng-controller="templateController ng-cloak">
Template ID: {{parameter.id}} </div>`

`<div ng-controller="templateController ">
 <span ng-bind="map.window"</span> </div>`

but, non of them solve it.

Can anyone save me?

Comment: I have the same problem +1

Comment: @mlivan Check below answer!!!

Comment: yes, that the one of the solution, but me need template and in template need defined new controller with new scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below answer is not mine, it's written by **cthrax** in Angular Google Map Team.(https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1399)

Hmm, it appears to be something to do with rendering the templateUrl. If you transclude the template, it seems to work much better. http://plnkr.co/edit/yluY5N0BI8Sv4fxUW9Pp?p=preview Not sure if that's a bug or a fact of life for recompiling the template.

```
      <ui-gmap-window show="map.window.show" coords="map.window.model" ng-cloak>
        <div ng-controller="templateController">
            Template ID: {{map.window.model.id}}
       </div>
      </ui-gmap-window>
```